# Tag datatables é indicada, porém não existe

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags

Ao tentar inserir uma dúvida de `datatables`(Plugin jQuery) encontrei o seguinte empecilho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na descrição é solicitado que eu use a tag `datatables`, porém a mesma não existe e também não posso criar.

Comment: Em situações assim - ou sempre que achar necessário/interessante usar certa tag que ainda não existe - faça a pergunta sem a tag específica, e peça pra alguém que já atingiu esse privilégio para criá-la pra você (na própria pergunta [comentário], no meta ou no chat).

Comment: O sistema não deixa criar a tag porque acha que é a mesma tag, no plural (e portanto devia ser um sinônimo). Só moderadores poderão criar essa tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei uma nova tag para o plugin de jQuery: [jquery-datatables](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables). Também atualizei o fragmento da wiki da tag [datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) para indicar essa nova tag, em vez da outra que o sistema não deixa criar.